# python class variable outside method when inheriting

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Lets say I have a class called `MyClass1`

```
class MyClass1:
    SOME = 'some'

class MyClass2(MyClass, MyClass1):
    def __init__(self):
        some cases here
    print(SOME) #case 1
    def new(self, value=SOME): #case2
        print(value)

    def old(self):
        print(self.SOME) #case3
```

Here case1 and case2 gives error while case3 executes.
I want case1 and case2 to happen. How can I do thaat ??

Need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SOME` exists within `MyClass1`'s class dictionary. Reference it thusly:

```
class MyClass1:
    SOME = 'some'

class MyClass2(MyClass1):
    def __init__(self):
        some cases here
    print(MyClass1.SOME) #case 1
    def new(self, value=MyClass1.SOME): #case2
        print(value)

    def old(self):
        print(self.SOME) #case3
```

Or use `super()`, if you're familiar with it.

Comment: What's the alternative? When you write `SOME` within the body of the `MyClass2` definition, a lookup is performed on the class dictionary of `MyClass2`, which is "under construction", so-to-speak, at the time the class definition is executed. If above `__init__` you were to write `SOME = MyClass1.SOME`, then your above code would work. As it is, though, the only way to access `SOME` is through the parent class.

Comment: A question then .. def old(some).. why I am able to access self.some also in my another class when I call MyClass2.SOME I am getting its value how that ?? Please explain if u dont mind

Comment: `self` is simply an instance of `MyClass2`. Whenever you attempt attribute access on such an instance, the name is looked up on the instance dictionary. If it isn't there, the name is looked up in the `MyClass2` class dictionary. If it isn't there, it is looked up on a parent class dictionary, in this case `MyClass1`. This is why `self.SOME` works in the `old` method.

Comment: Then when I acces it SOME from another script or class like MyClass2.SOME .. why I am getting its value then ??

Comment: Because it performs the attribute resolution I just described. It finds the value in the `MyClass1` class dictionary. To see this, try changing `MyClass1.SOME` and looking up `MyClass.SOME`. You'll see that the value has changed too.